# Memory leak in scipy?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scipy

I want to solve a least-square problem using some iterative solver. I need sparse matrices and scipy has the functions `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr()` and `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr()`. However, if I put them in a loop, the memory consumption explodes. So there seem to be a memory leak somewhere.

Here is an example of how it looks:

```
for i in range(0,200):
    print(i)
    tmp = sparse.linalg.lsmr(A_tot, np.asarray(b_tot.toarray().squeeze()))
    delta = tmp[0]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or if there are other solvers? I have tried both `lsqr` and `lsmr`.

Here is a related [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3762), but it is from 2014 and it is marked as solved. That is not my experience however.

When I try the following peace of code, the consumed memory is stable (not increasing):

This code reproduces the error:

```
A_tot2 = sparse.rand(128365, 535, density=0.05)
b_tot2 = sparse.rand(128365,1)
pdb.set_trace()
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    start = time.time()
    tmp = sparse.linalg.lsmr(A_tot2, b_tot2.toarray().squeeze())
    stop = time.time()
    print("Time: " + str(stop-start))
    delta = tmp[0]
    print(i)
    # pdb.set_trace()
```

The memory behavior can be seen in the image below. I have also tried to step forward using `pdb.set_trace()` with the same behavior. The memory increases as the loop iterates and it drops and starts to increase again. Above where it stands `15%` there is a small zig-zag pattern. That was for `density=0.01`.[image]

EDIT:

I just added `gc.collect()` at the bottom of the `for-loop` and that solved the issue. But, what is going on exactly? I do not really understand how Python works here.

A colleague suggested there could be circular references in `scipy.linalg.lsqr()` which prevented the memory from being released.

Comment: Could you provide `A_tot`, `b_tot` and `w`?!

Comment: The size is `(128365, 535)` so I do not know how to achieve that.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with, say, `A_tot = sparse.rand(128365, 535)`?  It is much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: Thanks for the tips with `sparse.rand()`. I have updated the question.

Comment: That doesn't look like memory leak to me. Looks like a typical pattern of accumulation of temp objects followed by GC. The fact, it always drops back to baseline indicates it's not leaking.

Comment: Is there a way to clear that? Never heard of that behavior before.

Comment: Do you mean there are a number of tmp's?